# How to use user-defined floating point types in <random>?

Tags: c++, random, floating-point

We have defined a parameterized floating-point type and tried to use it with the stdlib random package when we run into this roadblock:

```
        using Real = sw::google::bfloat<16>;
        using Rand = std::mt19937_64;
        Seed<Rand> seed;
        Rand rng(seed);
        std::uniform_real_distribution<Real> uid(-1.0, 1.0);
```

```
...
    // CLASS TEMPLATE uniform_real_distribution
template<class _Ty = double>
    class uniform_real_distribution
        : public uniform_real<_Ty>
    {   // uniform real distribution
public:
    _RNG_REQUIRE_REALTYPE(uniform_real_distribution, _Ty);
...
```

```
 #define _RNG_REQUIRE_REALTYPE(_RandType, _CheckedType) \
    static_assert(_Is_any_of_v<_CheckedType, float, double, long double>, \
        "invalid template argument for " #_RandType ": N4659 29.6.1.1 [rand.req.genl]/1d requires one of " \
        "float, double, or long double")
```

The *random* stdlib appears to be hard coded with native floating-point types only. 
Our floating-point types are supporting the same operators as native with additional numerical analysis annotations to guide scientific computation, so from a computational point of view they are equivalent.

Do we really have to implement a whole new shadow random library that takes our floating-point type? Otherwise stated, what is the best approach to get *random* to work with user-defined floating-point types?

Comment: I would not expect `random` in a standard library to support parameterized floating-point types. It would be a nuisance to do, requiring either specialized code that is rarely used or limits imposed on the parameterization. It could be affected by the base, the exponent range, whether subnormals are supported, where they begin, and other factors.

Comment: (I do not even see that `uniform_real_distribution` is well defined in the C++ standard. The definition reads as if the population were continuous, but the floating-point format is not continuous [in the normal sense on the reals], and the quantization affects how numbers should be chosen, especially in the interval you request, −1 to +1.)